# Firefox add-on without UI

Tags: firefox-addon

I want to develop firefox add-on(extension) which shouldn't have UI . I want execute some tasks whenever the webpage loads,, is it possible to achieve this ?

If anyone has useful links plz reply to this post

Answer (score 2):

NIn Firefox add-on sdk tool, you can use page-mod to achieve this:

```
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.org", // the url matcher of the page you want to modify
  contentScriptWhen: 'end', // when to load the tasks
  contentScript: '' // the javascript tasks you want to perform on page
});
```

It does not need to create an UI.

You can find out more about it at the documentation page for firefox add-on sdk (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/).

Comment: use `contentScriptFile: data.url("myScript.js")` to load javascript files.

Comment: Normally i need to use.xul file in the .manifest file . that will do registration for ur event-handler. How can i register this without .xul ?
you mean to say i cant do this without using SDK and using traditional XUL files ?

Comment: you can use XUL as well I believe. but i am not very familiar with XUL. using SDK appears to be easier for me.

Comment: but i read if u develop add-on using SDK, Firefox developed before may 2011 will not support it. is it true ?

Comment: SDK only supports Firefox 4+.

Answer (score 0):

First result: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=firefox+extension+on+page+load

First two results: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=firefox+extension+on+page+load